# C++ Class inheritance in Xcode?

Tags: objective-c, inheritance

I am just making a simple example of inheritance in C++. I am using Xcode and whenever I create a subclass I obtain the error: Use of undeclared identifier Rat. These are my classes:

> Pet.h

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Pet
{
  public:
  // Constructors, Destructors
  Pet(): weight(1), food("Pet Chow") {}
  ~Pet() {}

  //General methods
  void eat();
  void speak();

    protected:
        int weight;
        string food;
};
```

> Rat.h

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Pet.h"

using namespace std;

class Rat::public Pet
{
    Rat() {}
    ~Rat() {}
    // Other methods
    void sicken() { cout << "Spreading plague" << endl; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That was so dumb... Shame on me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you mean

```
class Rat : public Pet
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Rat::public Pet
```

should be

```
class Rat: public Pet
```